# Image not displayed in spring-boot version 1.5.3

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have been trying for more than an hour to display an image in my SpringBoot version 1.5.3 application.

I'm trying to display an image in my html page, which is the path:
[image: image location]

And have used the image as:

```
<img src="images/DataServicesAdminAppLogo.png" width="40" height="40" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="" hspace="10"/>
```

in my html page. But in vain. The image is not getting displayed.

Can someone please help?

**UPDATE**:

*Network Inspector*:
[image]

*ApplicationContext.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.2.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <!-- <context:component-scan base-package="com.csaa.mdm"></context:component-scan> -->

    <util:properties id="configLocProperties"
        location="file:${app.config.home}/config/config.properties" />
    <context:property-placeholder
        location="file:${app.config.home}/config/config.properties" />

    <bean id="configProperties"
        class="com.csaa.mdm.adminApp.util.ApplicationPropertyConfigurer">
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
        <property name="location">
            <value>file:${app.config.home}/config/config.properties
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="applicationPropertyUtil" class="com.csaa.mdm.adminApp.util.ApplicationPropertyUtil">
        <property name="propertyConfigurer" ref="configProperties" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="metaCryptoUtil" class="com.csaa.mdm.adminApp.util.CryptoUtil">
        <property name="userId" value="${oracle.meta.username}"></property>
        <property name="password" value="${oracle.meta.password}"></property>
        <property name="key" value="123456789012345678901234"></property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Create datasource and give connection properties -->
    <bean id="metaDatasource" primary="true"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${oracle.db.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${oracle.db.dev.connection}" />
        <property name="username" value="#{metaCryptoUtil.userId}" />
        <property name="password" value="#{metaCryptoUtil.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="metaDatasource" />
    </bean>


    <!-- Create the dao object and pass the datasource to it -->
    <bean id="adminDao" class="com.csaa.mdm.adminApp.dao.AdminDao">
        <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="adminUtil" class="com.csaa.mdm.adminApp.util.AdminUtil">
        <property name="configProperties" ref="configLocProperties"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate" />
</beans>
```

Comment: Use Inspector in your browser and go to the Network tab. You'll see the exact request for the image file, and what the server responds with. 90% likely that will reveal the problem.

Comment: I have added my Network inspector. Pls check my update David.

Comment: After opening the network tab, hit Reload.

Comment: Try without setting any resourceHandlers as SpringBoot will automatically load everything from the static or the public folders in the resource folder. Also in Network tab click PreserveLog so that history of calls are saved, search your image url call in the list.

Comment: Yes. Knew that. I wasn't having resource handler earlier @Amit. It didn't work either. It was now I added it.

Comment: If you don't see an attempt to fetch the image in the Network tab, then go to View Source and see if the img tag is actually making it to the browser. Reload some other (working) pages with the Network tab open to get a feel for how it works. Look for 200 (and 304) status codes. Then look for similar codes on your page.

Comment: The Networks tab has an info "Request URL: http://localhost:8080/images/DataServicesAdminAppLogo.png"

Comment: Yes David. The img tag is available. But is showing the wrong location of the image path.

Comment: can you share `applicationContext.xml`?

Comment: Updated @AmitKBist

Comment: I have a few pages after this login, which is showing this logo ! Only my login page doesn't reflect this ! Possibly because I'm redirecting every "/" to login page.